# UUID for user unique ID?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, uuid, aws-amplify

Whenever we create an authentication system it always creates a unique ID automatically just like UUID for every user. In my authentication system(amazon-cognito) it is asking for a username and email for signup a user & username should be unique and immutable. But I want that user can change username later that is why I added sign-in through preferred username and user can add preferred username after email verification and can change it. That username during signup is useless because it is creating a sub(unique ID) for every user separately after sign-up. In the signup username place I'm using UUID.

**PROCESS**

1. For sign up need a unique username(immutable) & email.
2. After email conformation user will chose there preferred username. Preferred username is also unique but user can change it later and can sign-in using it.
3. After user creation amazoncognito is creating an unique ID for every user.
4. Now user can sign-in through username(given during signup),preferred username & email.
5. But I don't want to take username during signup from user because that can't be updated by user in later  time and technically user should have one username which should be mutable that is preferred username.
6. That is why I am using UUID in place username during signing up a user. Is that a good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Internally a UUID is just fine but I'd not require the user to enter it for authentication. That would be quite the hassle and would also potentially make the user id PII.

Comment: now you can check

Answer (score 1):

I think **yes** is the answer to your question.

I do it by myself in my projects.

I say you why!

The usual auto-incremented id works perfectly fine. Well, there are a few cases where UUID might become handy. Even though excellent web portals have widely used UUID identifiers as primary ID systems (https://trello.com, https://slack.com), many new start-ups and developments are still based on auto-incremented primary keys as IDs.

- One is related to security. A UUID is way more challenging to remember than a simple number. So someone passing by, glancing at your screen, would not be able to know what file number you are working on. Hacking into a system to retrieve information is way more difficult if you don't see what you're looking for or where to look.
- Another is concerning database scaling. Imagine you've been writing blog articles on two self-hosted blogging platforms. And for some reason, you want to merge those two blogs into one. If you had used the usual auto-incrementing IDs, you would have to re-index every blog post of the databases and update every foreign key that might point to them. But if you had used UUID as primary keys… No work to do!
- If you use Autoincrement IDs, a bad guy could create an account in your system, create a company, check the Network tab in the Chrome browser and see that his ID is 136. He now knows that your system has only 135 companies ever created by other clients. You may say "not a big deal," but are you 100% sure the total entity count info put is not sensitive?
- When you use UUIDs, you can't say how many records were created before. Also, you could use UUIDv4 in secret (e.g. share) links. Hackers will need eternity to guess it even if you will have millions of secret links.

There are indeed some other benefits to using UUID as primary keys; look around on the internet.

Ultimately, this is your project, and you should decide which strategy fits your project the best.

Comment: Bro that UUID I am providing as a username during signup is kind of useless because amazoncognito is also creating a unique ID separately basically known as "sub". And my question is what is the chance of collision of UUID ,same UUID generation 2times

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. A collision is possible, but the total number of unique keys generated is so large that the possibility of a collision is almost zero. As per Wikipedia, the number of UUIDs generated to have at least 1 collision is 2.71 quintillion. This is equivalent to generating around 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years!